# Help on making money faster on TERA

Tags: tera

I'm having a really hard time to get some money for myself.

I've used to do ALL dungeons and I used to get around 2-3k a day.

But since the last update, I have focused on getting the latest PVP gear.
As you may know, battlegrounds give little money: ~45g per victory + ~40g for the daily quest.

How can I make some money faster?

---

I don't have anything I can sell, but I'm willing to invest. Bear in mind that I only have 150g.

If it matters, I'm on Arcadia (EU) server and I'm level 65.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I'd suggest seeing if you can find a static group, and run all of the new dungeons.  I'm not altogether too sure what everything is selling for on the EU servers, but I know that the drops from the new dungeons are selling for a pretty decent amount of gold on the US servers.

Right now, Ancient Wishes are selling somewhere around 60k a piece, if I remember correctly, and I know that designs for tier three etchings and master alchemy recipes.

You could also run battlegrounds for boxes- again, I don't know the prices on EU Tera, but Champion's Oils (and the boxes themselves) sell for a fairly decent price (a few thousand a piece), so that's something you could do as well.

I've heard that inflation on the EU servers is pretty damned excessive, so take these prices that I've given with more than just a little bit of leeway.  They're fairly rare drops, which is why they sell for a considerable amount, and also why I would suggest a static group.  (And if you can't find one to split profits with, you could always queue for instance matching, if worst comes to worst.)

Then there's always the option of selling cash shop items, but if you were to go this route, it might take a while.

Anyway, I hope that you figure out some way to make decent gold fairly soon!  Best of luck!

Comment: The gear in the dungeons isn't tradeable. As long as I know. The crafted one is, but has been a week that I don't play with my main. Today, I've got 2 `Champion's Oil`s and I've put on Trade Broker. I'm waiting for them to be sold for 2.35k. Selling alkahest is alright too, but it's hard to get when you are unlucky. But thanks for the tips. My +1 on this one.